# HTC Cha Cha - wont start

Tags: htc-chacha

I have problem with my HTC Cha Cha.
After trying to start I see welcome screen, then black screen and sound signal, then welcome screen... and in infinite loop, I have to take out battery to stop it.
Any suggestions what to do? I can plug it with USB cable to computer and try to perform some actions, but I have no experience in fixing Android.

Comment: What where you doing with the device before it started doing this? i.e what trigged it to get suck in a bootloop

Comment: I don't know, is this actual cause, but I plugged discharged phone to charger and second after that I tried tu turn it on. After that I have this problem.

Comment: If it was completely discharged and dead I suggest plugging it into a mains socket for a good couple of hours then try again

Comment: @ZacPowell I have tried to charge it from yesterday, also removing battery for few minutes.